# Highlight rows until a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

How can I modify my code to select the rows  until column L instead of the entire row?

Sub trial()

```
Dim c As Range
Dim rngG As Range
For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("f"))
    If c >= 1 Then

        If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = c.EntireRow
        Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.EntireRow)
    End If
Next c
rngG.Select
```

End Sub

Comment: What's the value of `c`?

Comment: C is the value for column F if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just add an intersect to,

```
    If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = c.EntireRow
    Set rngG = Union(rngG, c.EntireRow)
```

... like,

```
    If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = intersect(range("A:L").entirecolumn, c.EntireRow)
    Set rngG = Union(rngG, intersect(range("A:L").entirecolumn, c.EntireRow))
```

TBH, I'm not sure if .entirecolumn is completely necessary but I ran into this issue a while back and adding .entirecolumn was the fix.

```
Dim c As Range, rngG As Range

For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Columns("f"))
    If c >= 1 Then
        If rngG Is Nothing Then Set rngG = intersect(range("A:L").entirecolumn, c.EntireRow)
        Set rngG = Union(rngG, intersect(range("A:L").entirecolumn, c.EntireRow))
    End If
Next c
rngG.Select
```

Comment: I did the changes like you suggested but it says compile error Next without for though.

Comment: Hi ,@Jeeped it works! Thank you for your help, Appreciate it!